# LINQ Query result to object

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a XML document where I store some data, I need to query the data in that file and get a single record, I do it using this code

```
   xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("Data.xml");
   var updateQuery = (from item in xmlDoc.Descendants("Event")
                      where item.Element("id").Value == id
                      select item).FirstOrDefault();
```

```
public class Event
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Contact> contacts { get; set; }
}
```

```
<Event>
    <id>1</id>
    <title>AA</title>
    <start>2019-12-01T14:13:58.863</start>
    <end>2019-12-01T15:13:58.787</end>
    <contacts>

      <contact>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>ABC</name>
      </contact>

      <contact>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>ABCD</name>
      </contact>

      <contact>
        <id>3</id>
        <name>ABCDE</name>
      </contact>

    </contacts>
  </Event>
```

I get the results perfectly but I need to get the data in to the Event object, how can I achieve this?

Comment: What `Event` object?

Comment: is `Event` object a custom class?, if yes then transforming the selected `XElement` to `Event` object isn't specifically related to `LINQ`

Comment: I would suggest creating a `public static Event FromXElement(XElement element)` method. Implementing that is entirely separate from the query part - have you tried writing any code to convert an element into an `Event` yet? What happened?

Comment: extending on Jon's comment, to start with you can do
`var eventObject = new  Event { id = element.Decedents('id').FirstOrDefault().Value}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select a new `Event` from each item:

```
var event = (from item in xmlDoc.Descendants("Event")
            where item.Element("id").Value == id
            select new Event
            {
                id = item.Element("id").Value,
                title = item.Element("title").Value,
                Start = DateTime.Parse(item.Element("start").Value),
                End = DateTime.Parse(item.Element("end").Value),
                contacts = item.Element("contacts").Elements("contact").Select(c => new Contact
                {
                    Id = c.Element("id").Value,
                    Name = c.Element("name").Value
                }).ToList()
            }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Of course, you can break this mapping out to a separate method and use `select MyMappingMethod(item)` for reusability.